# Issue calculating time difference c#

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, unix-timestamp

I have a check i run on the server and on a desktop application but the result is not consistent.

This is the code on the server to add a timestamp to a string which i send back to the desktop app. So that the returned string expires after some time and cannot be used as it is encrypted.

Server:

```
Double unixTimestamp = (double)(DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))).TotalSeconds;
DateTime TodayDate = UnixTimeStampToDateTime(unixTimestamp);
```

Desktop App:

```
//li.tStamp this comes from the server

DateTime time = UnixTimeStampToDateTime(Convert.ToDouble(li.tStamp));
Double unixTimestamp = (double)(DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))).TotalSeconds;
DateTime time2 = UnixTimeStampToDateTime(unixTimestamp);
```

The condition:

```
double SecondsDifference = time2.Subtract(time).TotalSeconds;
if (SecondsDifference > 0 && SecondsDifference < 30)
{
    // DO SOMETHING HERE
}
```

The thing is the result is not consistent it works on some pc an not on another what am I doing wrong here?

```
public static DateTime UnixTimeStampToDateTime(double unixTimeStamp)
{
    // Unix timestamp is seconds past epoch
    System.DateTime dtDateTime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, System.DateTimeKind.Utc);
    dtDateTime = dtDateTime.AddSeconds(unixTimeStamp).ToLocalTime();
    return dtDateTime;
}
```

Comment: I'm suspecting that it is related to the value of the `DateTimeKind` property - with the first examples it's set to `Unspecified`, with the last example it's set to `Utc`. I think you should set it to `Utc` always.

Comment: The unix epoch is always UTC.  That makes new DateTime(1970, 1, 1) wrong, it will be interpreted as local time.  Note how UnixTimeStampToDateTime() did it right.

Comment: Can you explain what consistency you expect ?

Comment: Why are you using `.ToLocalTime();`? What if the `SecondsDifference` is negative? Some computers may not be timesync

Comment: @J.vanLangen found this sampel online on how to convert unix timestamp to datetime.

Comment: "The condition" is broken for TimeZones that have DayLightSavings. (Given that time2 is local time) You should convert to utc, subtract, then convert back to local.

Comment: Also mind that if you are doing XML Serialization in there somewhere, the serializer will convert automatically, too. It expects DateTimes to be local, converts to UTC, serializes, then on the other end deserializes to UTC and converts to local. (At least last time I had to deal with this.)

Comment: apart from the current question is this the rite way to ad licensing etc to your app so some one cannot reuse the encrypted string containing license info etc as it expires with some time

Comment: It's not reliable way as machines can be de-synchronized. Typically the time is synchronized by NTP protocol which may achieve accuracy up to 60ms for WAN (the best case). But if your computers are in a LAN the transmission time can be less than this value and you can get even negative difference sometime because condition depends on two unreliable factors - the synchronization accuracy on both machines and transmission time which may vary from time to time.

Comment: @DmytroMukalov what else can i do for the matter above

Comment: I'm not sure what the final goal is but general suggestion is to make time verification on a single machine, say server, and then send only result of the verificarion (unless you have atomic clock hardware side by side with the servers like Google Spanner has).

Comment: @DmytroMukalov  if we do that i have seen in the past you can make changes to pc config files and it will go to some other address when you hit the website and they can just copy paste the returned string and send over. Basically the check is to make sure the returned string is not longer than 1 minute old so it cannot be reused like the way above.

Comment: I'm not giving you suggestions of how to implement functionality to fit your requirements, I'm merely giving suggestion of how to potentially deal with expiration verification and why it's not reliable to do in a distributed manner. You can take it into consideration or not - it's up to you but here on SO no one will  architect a complete solution for you as only you know all scenarios, constraints and requirements the solution should follow.